# next js npx create-next-app@latest not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, next.js, npx

I'm having trouble with "npx create-next-app@latest" command while trying to set up Next.js. I'm new to the community and also to Next.js and I need some help to solve this issue. When I ran the command, it showed some message that I couldn't understand. How can I fix it?

Also, I'm running Node.js version v21.1.0 and npm version 10.2.0. I have attached a screenshot of the error message for your reference.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 3):

#### Step 1: Open Command Prompt as Administrator

- Click on the Start Menu or press the Windows key.
- Type "cmd" or "Command Prompt" in the search bar.
- Right-click on "Command Prompt" from the search results and select "Run as administrator".

#### Step 2: Clear npm Cache

- In the Command Prompt, type the following command and then press Enter:

  ```
  npm cache clean --force
  ```
- You'll see a warning message; this is normal. The command forces npm to clear any stored data that might be causing issues.

#### Step 3: Check npm and Node.js Installation

- Let's make sure npm and Node.js are correctly installed. Type these commands one at a time and press Enter after each:

  ```
  node -v
  npm -v
  ```
- These commands will tell you the version of Node.js and npm installed on your system. Make sure they show the version numbers without errors.

#### Step 4: Reinstall Node.js and npm (if Step 3 fails)

- If you received an error or didn't see the version numbers in Step 3, you might need to reinstall Node.js and npm.
- Visit the official [Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/).
- Download the "LTS" version recommended for most users.
- Run the downloaded installer, following the prompts to reinstall Node.js and npm.
- After installation, restart your Command Prompt and repeat Step 3 to ensure Node.js and npm are installed correctly.

#### Step 5: Create Your Next.js App

- In the Command Prompt, navigate to the folder where you want your Next.js app to be created.
- Run the following command:

  ```
  npx create-next-app@latest my-next-app
  ```
- Replace `my-next-app` with your desired project name.
- If you see any prompts, follow the instructions provided in the Command Prompt.

#### Step 6: Navigate to Your New App's Directory

- Once the app is created, move into your app's directory by typing:

  ```
  cd my-next-app
  ```
- Replace `my-next-app` with the actual name of your app's directory.

#### Step 7: Start the Development Server

- Inside your app's directory, start the development server by running:

  ```
  npm run dev
  ```
- This will start the Next.js development server on your local machine.

#### Step 8: Access Your Next.js App

- Open your web browser and enter the following URL:

  ```
  http://localhost:3000
  ```
- You should see your new Next.js app running!

---